# What is the maximum achievable height of a creature self-concentrating under the spell Fly?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, flight

How high can someone go using only one (1) *[fly](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fly)* spell? No other means of movement or ways to change your position are allowed besides movement under *fly*. Assume a level 20 character with all stats at 20, plus any relevant bonuses, as well as limitless preparation time prior to lift-off. No magic items allowed. Outside assistance is permitted, but reliance on chance (such as needing a specific result on the Wild Magic Surge table) is not. Also, spells such as *Dimension Door* and *Teleport* that allow you to obtain altitude without flying and techniques to "move without movement" are not allowed, as I am asking for aviation with *Fly*.

Get creative! I love seeing wild shenanigans to reach arbitrary theoretical maximums!

---

Related for anyone concerned with the minimum height you fly with the *Fly* spell: [How high off the ground can you fly with the Fly spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149887/how-high-off-the-ground-can-you-fly-with-the-fly-spell)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Assuming you have enough height: 166,100 ft ≈ 31.46 miles

The first thing to recognize is that *fly* grants the creature's bonuses to its speed will also apply to this flying speed (as long as it isn't specific to walking speed). In no particular order:

- Sorcerer 11 (for Extended spell and spell slots seen later)
- Borrowed Transmuter's Stone (10 ft)
- Barbarian 5's Fast Movement (10 ft)
- Monk 3 (10 ft)
- *Longstrider* (10 ft)
- Mobile feat (10 ft)

We then want friends to cast *expeditious retreat*, and *fly* (both Extended). We will spend our spell slots and concentration on Extended *haste*'s (since it only lasts 2 minutes will need to recast it a few times).

By using our normal, bonus, and *haste* action each turn to Dash, we'll move four times our speed each turn. However, we'll have *haste* ending and the lethargy + recasting costs us 5 moves (one turn's and the action to recast) for the nine times will have to do it (before *fly* elapses). Oh, and *haste* doubles our speed. So we'll get to move
$$
(60+10+10+10+10+10)\text{ ft.}\times2\times(4\times20\times10-5\times9) = 166100 \text{ ft.} \approx 31.46 \text{ miles}
$$

Comment: Thank you for actually giving an answer. Now that I have changed the question, perhaps you have even better shenanigans to reach for the stars?

Comment: As long as you're in sight/hearing range, you could have a Battlemaster using Maneuvering Attack to give you a half-move as a reaction. It's still using your own movement and fly speed so I think it still counts under the OP's restrictions.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Sight range is capped at 2 miles, and hearing seems to end at around 120 ft. I don't think it changes the calculation much anyways.

Comment: Assuming no assistance from Eyes of the Eagle or whatnot, it's 2 miles, then. You should have ample time for your Battlemaster buddy to use his entire supply of 6 maneuvers for a half-move each time, or three additional move actions at a speed of 220, for a total of +660 feet.  It's not nothin'.

Comment: Even if sight range is capped, you could always have a second group pull the same kind of shenanigans, or even just use teleportation magic, to keep the Battlemaster in sight/hearing range.